# Amazon CloudFront bucket returning 403 Forbidden at one endpoint

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have an Amazon CloudFront distribution backed by an S3 bucket. There is a file that I update from our backend server every 10 minutes with a header expire time of 9m50s. This file is read by our software (Mac and Windows product).

This file is in a "folder" (I realize S3 really doesn't have folders) called "/mac/myfile.gz". There is an identical file in "/win/myfile.gz" and each is used by the respective version of our software.

Recently, I am seeing a long series of 403 errors in my Amazon Logs, but it is only happening to the file in the "/mac/" folder.

1. All the file requests are coming from our software as expected.
2. The 403 errors all come from Amazon's `JFK51-C1` and from the same IP.
3. All 403 errors have an `x-edge-result-type` of `Error`
4. All 403 errors have an `x-edge-response-result` of `Error`

Even more curiously, on the "/win/" file, the `x-edge-result-type` is a good mix of `Hit` and `Miss`. However on the "/mac/" side even when the `sc-status` is 200, and the requests come from all over the world, the `x-edge-result-type` is either `Miss` or `Error`, and never `Hit`.

Any idea why this file is not being correctly distributed while all the others are?

EDITED TO ADD:

Bucket Policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity ABCDEFG1234567"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket.namehere.com/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you post the bucket policy and/or the object ACL of the problematic bucket/object?

Comment: Edited above. I can access the file from here perfectly fine and thousands of others can too, but I have one endpoint/IP that is getting 403 constantly over the past week or so. It is intermittent, so hard to figure out.

Comment: The bucket policy looks good to me. Can you try to invalidate the cache of that object and see if the problem occurs again?